# Sorting by Duplicates in Two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of names and phone numbers. There are duplicates in both columns.

With the following code, I get the table sorted by phone, *but if there are any name duplicates*, those are clustered together:

```
SELECT 
    a.[name], 
    a.phone
FROM 
    Tests.dbo.sort_test6 AS a
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        [name], 
        MIN(phone) AS min_phone_by_name
    FROM 
        Tests.dbo.sort_test6 
    GROUP BY 
        [name]
) AS dt
ON a.[name] = dt.[name]
ORDER BY min_phone_by_name, [name], phone
```

The result is very good; it's all in order by *phone*, but the names are clustered if there are any duplicates:

| name | phone |
| --- | --- |
| Eve | 098 |
| Eve | 365 |
| Eve | 789 |
| Nack | 098 |
| Adam | 123 |
| Adam | 345 |
| Adam | 346 |
| Oiu | 145 |
| Tom | 145 |
| Nic | 146 |
| James | 156 |
| Sam | 177 |
| Sam | 443 |
| Sam | 777 |
| Tim | 256 |
| Will | 256 |
| Sara | 333 |
| Dav | 345 |

Phone **345** that belongs to Adam *and* Dav is my issue.

What I want is for that 345 to be brought up to the 345 in the Adam cluster, **but only at the end of the Adam cluster**. So exactly like this:

| name | phone |
| --- | --- |
| Eve | 098 |
| Eve | 365 |
| Eve | 789 |
| Nack | 098 |
| Adam | 123 |
| Adam | 345 |
| Adam | 346 |
| Dav | 345 |
| Oiu | 145 |
| Tom | 145 |
| Nic | 146 |
| James | 156 |
| Sam | 177 |
| Sam | 443 |
| Sam | 777 |
| Tim | 256 |
| Will | 256 |
| Sara | 333 |

EDIT: Here is the table I'm working with if this will help:

```
CREATE TABLE Tests.dbo.sort_test6
(
    name VARCHAR(10),
    phone CHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO Tests.dbo.sort_test6
VALUES
('Adam', '345'),
('Adam', '345'),
('Adam', '123'),
('Dav', '345'),
('Dav', '999'),
('Dav', '555'),
('Dav', '699'),
('Dav', '112'),
('Dav', '112'),
('Dav', '112'),
('Dav', '112'),
('Rob', '456'),
('Rick', '645'),
('Rick', '876'),
('Eve', '365'),
('Eve', '098'),
('Eve', '789'),
('Si', '876'),
('Will', '256'),
('Chad', '876'),
('James', '156'),
('Dirk', '844'),
('Chaz', '513'),
('Dob', '513'),
('Ron', '513'),
('Gil', '513'),
('Jack', '725'),
('Nack', '098'),
('Oiu', '145'),
('Uva', '765'),
('Tom', '145'),
('Chaz', '736'),
('Chaz', '875'),
('Chaz', '875'),
('Chaz', '875'),
('Chaz', '875'),
('Chaz', '875'),
('Chaz', '875'),
('Chaz', '731'),
('Laz', '763'),
('Nic', '146'),
('Sam', '177'),
('Sam', '777'),
('Sam', '443'),
('Chim', '777'),
('Sara', '333'),
('Tim', '256'),
('Ted', '731'),
('zed', '731'),
('Tam', '146'),
('Zam', '146'),
('Lam', '146'),
('Tom', '215'),
('Sam', '146')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this. Here is my take on this problem. Also, you have "Dav" at the wrong place in your desired output according to your explanation.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by phone)
    from SortDemo
)
select sd.name
    , sd.phone
from SortedResults sr
join SortDemo sd on sd.name = sr.name
where sr.RowNum = 1
order by sr.phone
    , sd.name
```

Comment: This works. Thank you!

Comment: Err, actually when I run this I get the same result as my original query, sorry false alarm. Not sure if I am missing something.